# Instagram API /users/search method is not working as expected

Tags: api, instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

I have a Windows application which uses Instagram API. A user does not authenticate in it, he just enters his username and my application makes a request to a [public `/users/search` method](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search) in order to get the user's ID.

Now, I have faced the following problem:

When I query Instagram API with a short user name (like `ffff`), it returns a list of found users. However, this list does not contain the user with this **exact** username.

For example, there is a user `ffff` in Instagram. It does exist, for sure ([link to his page](https://instagram.com/ffff)).

When I execute API method `/users/search` with `ffff` query, I get a lot of users having `ffff` **as a part of their username**; or **as a part of their full name**; but definitely not a user having **exactly the same username**.

Here is [an example API request](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=ffff&client_id=8035129ee63e4f25a8a90f174bc65ab1) which returns a list of users. However, there is no user with username `ffff` in a result while it would be pretty logical to return him. Moreover, as for me, I would expect to see him **as a first item in an array** so that I can make `&count=1` request and be sure that it will be found, instead of getting 100 users and filtering them. It is not a security issue or whatever else - their search engine just guesses for some reason, that these users are more interesting for me.

I am just wondering how such a popular social network can have such a poor API - now, it looks like I just can't work with users who have too simple, broad or popular usernames.

The only thing I want is to **get a single user's ID by his exact username** - that's exactly what this endpoint API function should do. "Search for a user by name.", according to [API documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search). How to achieve this?

Of course, the first thing I have done was a message to their support. However, I still haven't received any answer or commentary.

Comment: Yes, actually, I know one way to achieve this. Open user's profile page like https://instagram.com/ffff and parse HTML contents. However, making this while the application has public API sounds strange for me.

Comment: I'm with you. Probably we need /users/{username} endpoint to get basic information about a user, instead of /users/search. I need to generate user link from comment string which includes mention (@username). /users/search isn't suitable for this case.

Comment: Did you end up finding some type of workaround?

Comment: @RooWM Unfortunatelly, no. Some users having such usernames are unable to use our app. Afaik, recently Instagram API has been updated. I haven't reviewed this update yet, but it may contain required methods :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev We ended up scraping the image data from the user's page—pretty hacky, but works if you're just pulling images.